# How to distinguish function definitions and function declarations in Clang AST visitors

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I have developed an AST visitor using Clang libtooling and I would like to distinguish between function prototypes and function declarations. My AST visitor takes both cases as function declarations. Below you can see my code for visiting function declarations:

```
bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *func)
   {
      if(astContext->getSourceManager().isInMainFile(func->getLocStart()) && func->hasBody()) //checks if the node is in the main (input) file.
      {
           FullSourceLoc FullLocation = astContext->getFullLoc(func->getLocStart());
           string funcName = func->getNameInfo().getName().getAsString();
           string funcType = func->getResultType().getAsString();
           string srcFunc = filename + "_" + funcName;
           REPORT << "Function Declaration [" << FullLocation.getSpellingLineNumber() << "," << FullLocation.getSpellingColumnNumber() << "]: " <<  funcName << " of type " << funcType << "\n";
           if (append == 0 && numFunctions == 0)
              APIs << srcFunc <<":";
           else
              APIs << "\n" << srcFunc <<":";
           APIs  <<funcType << ",";
           numFunctions++;
       }
       return true;
    }
```

func->hasBody() cannot distinguish between those two things. Any ideas??

Comment: What makes you think those are two different things? Can you give some examples? Or do you mean function declarations and function definitions?

Comment: Yeah i meant to distinguish between function definitions and declarations.

Comment: Then please update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FunctionDecl::isThisDeclarationADefinition()`.